# disabling an input via a function nextjs

Tags: javascript, next.js, react-bootstrap

So i have an input slider, that i want to disable if the `loggedInUser` doesnt meet the role requirements for that input, for example, if the input requires an accountant level role, and the user does not have that `role` the input should be disabled, it will still be visible, but i want it disabled.

now normally id solve this by doing `disabled={!loggedInUser.isAccountant}` this is usually all thats needed. However, i have other inputs where several roles should be able to access this input but that user may not have all of the roles, for example, i may want an accountant and an admin to access this input, but not a `partner` though i still want the field to be viewable.

so i tried coming up with a function that would take the `loggedInUser`'s `user` document and loop over the `keys` on that document and try matching the `key` to a `role` thats passed in. if any of the roles match a key on the `user` document, it should check if (the key/value is a boolean) if the boolean is true, if it is, it should return the `true` boolean, (i.e., they have that role(s) needed to access this). However no matter what i do, all i get is a returned `Promise<Pending>` when i try to insert the function into the disabled prop on the component.

here is the input:

```
<Form.Group className={styles.boolean} controlId="isPaid">
            {/* True/False */}
            <Form.Check
              type="switch"
              id="custom-switch"
              label="Is Paid User"
              checked={formData.isPaidUser}
              onChange={(e) =>
                setFormData({
                  ...formData,
                  isPaidUser: !formData.isPaidUser,
                })
              }
              // Problem is here!
              disabled={checkRole(loggedInUser, ['isAdmin', 'isAccountant']}
            ></Form.Check>
          </Form.Group>
```

here is the `checkRole` function

```
/**
 * @description Check if the user has the role passed in the array, passing in multiple roles will check if the user has any of the roles
 * @param {Object} user - The logged in user object
 * @param {Array} roles - The roles to check against
 * @returns {Boolean} - Returns true if the user has the role, false if not
 * @example checkrole({user}, ['isAdmin'])
 * @example checkrole({user}, ['isAdmin', 'isPartner'])
 *
 * @author   Austin Howard
 * @version  1.0.1
 * @since    1.0.0
 * 
 */
export default async (user, roles) => {
  if (!user) return false;
  // roles is an array of roles to check against the user object,
  // we need to loop over the keys of the user object till we find a key that matches the role passed in the array
  // if the user has the role, check the boolean value of the key, if the value is true, return true else return false
  // if the user does not have the role, return false
  let hasRole = false;
  await Object.keys(user).forEach((key) => {
    console.log(`key: ${key}`);
    if (roles.includes(key)) {
      console.log(`user[key]: ${user[key]}`);
      if (user[key]) {
        console.log(`setting hasRole to true`);
        hasRole = true;
      }
    }
  });
  return hasRole;
};
```

I've tried multiple iterations of calling the function, even so far as setting up a self calling async function to encaspulate the `checkRole` function however no matter what i try, it will not insert the boolean as i need correctly

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like an asynchronous operation, try a synchronous method like

```
function userHasRole(user, roles){
  return roles.some(role => user[role]);
}
```

Comment: No dice, same thing is happening, i believe the problem itself isnt in the `checkRole` function but in the component itself on the `disabled` prop. For instance, while using your code does indeed return a true false value, its not being read on the disabled prop, and is therefore not managing the component correctly.

Comment: Also, i've used the function elsewhere to conditionally render components, so i know that its reading the function correctly i just cant figure out why its not reading it on the disabled input, since all it returns is a boolean, i figured this would be pretty straightforward

Comment: are there any errors in the console?

Comment: Unfortunately no, i have console logged the steps through to see what happens, the only error that is occuring in my window is that of a uncontrolled component being controlled, which is usually an error with setting form defaults and changing characters that shouldnt be changed, i dont think its whats causing the issue. it seems that the `disabled` prop only wants to read a `true/false` value and not a conditional, though i have gotten ternary's to work before. it just doesnt want to read the function output as a true/false value.

Comment: So, after some playing around with it, the only way i was able to make this work was by using `useState` and `useEffect` hooks, ill post an answer since this seems to work, however id still be interested in a more mainline solution that i wouldnt need to use these hooks in order to acheive the desired affect

Answer (score 0):

So after playing around i was able to make this work by using `useState` and `useEffect` hooks, that the form input will use to determine whether or not to disable the input.

so it looks a lot like this

```
const Form () => {
    const [disableFormInput, setDisableFormInput] = React.useState(false); //initial
React.useEffect(() => {
    if (user) {
      // setup a self-invoking function to check if the user has the correct user roles
      (async () => {
        setCanDelete(await checkRole(loggedInUser, ['isAdmin']));
      })();
    }
}, [user]);
...,
// function returns true if they have the role, we only want it disabled if they dont have the role.
<input disabled={!disableFormInput} ... />
```

Answer (score 0):

With the help of a colleague, i've found a better solution, that requires less code, and is more scalable, the above answer, my first answer, is a complete answer it works, but it is a bit hacky, so here is another one.

use Regex testing to return a boolean, so the `user` has a field `role` which is a string of different `roles` that the user has for example `admin accountant partner` on the `loggedInUser` Object i was setting booleans for easy use on the front end, based on the role the user had, however if i just use the string value, i can use RegEx testing to test if the user has the requested roles

so the final solution:

```
<input disabled={!/accountant|admin|partner/.test(loggedInUser.role)} ... />
```

This will scale a lot easier than the first answer i posted.